# SfB server shows error "The XMPP Translating Gateway failed to connect to a configured edge proxy."

Tags: skype-for-business-2016

I have the following SfB (= Skype for Business) environment:

*Site A:*

- Primary SfB Frontend Pool (3 Server = sfbfronta01/sfbfronta02/sfbfronta03)
- Primary SfB Edge Pool (2 Server = sfbedgea01/sfbedgea02)
- XMPP Federation is enabled here

*Site B:*

- additional SfB Frontend Pool (3 Server = sfbfrontb01/sfbfrontb02/sfbfrontb03)
- additional SfB Edge Pool (2 Server = sfbedgeb01/sfbedgeb02)
- XMPP Federation is *NOT* enabled here, as we use the primary pool for that

On all the SfB frontend server in site B I see the following error multiple times per day in the eventlog:

> The XMPP Translating Gateway failed to connect to a configured edge
>   proxy.
>
> sfbedgea01.internal.contoso.com. Resolution: Verify that each configured
>   edge proxy is running.

or the same for the 2nd edge server:

> The XMPP Translating Gateway failed to connect to a configured edge
>   proxy.
>
> sfbedgea02.internal.contoso.com. Resolution: Verify that each configured
>   edge proxy is running.

What I tried/checked so far is the following:

- Make sure no Antivirus is blocking the connection
- Installed the latest updates
- Rebooted the whole environment
- Checked port [23456](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618373(v=ocs.15).aspx) from Frontend pool in site B to Edge Pool in Site A via telnet which was working
- A SfB user in site B can send a chat message to a user on a 3rd party XMPP server
- DNS problems (e.g. wrong DNS entries, old DNS entries, ...)